# Currency table in CSS

Tags: css, html-table, formatting

I have a table and I need to format the currency in order for the `.` to be displayed always under each other.

This is the table:

```html
<table class="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Field1</th>
        <th>Field2</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="verticalDivider"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08 April 2010</td>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>GBP 20.00</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>GBP 20.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08 May 2010</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
        <td>GBP 100.00</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>GBP 1020.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19 May 2010</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>GBP 50.00</td>
        <td>GBP 970.00</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This jQuery plugin makes this easy: https://github.com/ndp/align-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?

```html
<style type="text/css">
    .price {
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

<table class="data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Field1</th>
        <th>Field2</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="verticalDivider"></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08 April 2010</td>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 20.00</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 20.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08 May 2010</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 100.00</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 1020.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>19 May 2010</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 50.00</td>
        <td class="price">GBP 970.00</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: obviously i would place the css at the top in a seperate stylesheet.

Comment: what I needed was to align the word GBP under each other and the decimals under each other as well. I managed to this using nested tables but it was not worth it so I used the align right instead.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you'll always print 2 decimal digits, I would define all my table `<col />` then I'd assign text-align : right to that cols that contain prices (and padding-right to create space from border)

otherwise as specified in http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.3.2 you could assign `align="char" char="."` to table cols (if you browser support it)

Answer (score 1):

To have the currency symbol (GBP) AND the dots aligned you can do the following (tested on Chrome and Firefox, breaks on IE):

CSS file:

```
...
td.money {
    text-align: right;
}

.currencySymbol {
    float: left;
}
...
```

And your table cell would look like:

```
<td class="money">
    <div class="currencySymbol">GBP</div>
    970.00
</td>
```

Although it's dangerous (probably the reason why it breaks on IE), see: [Is a DIV inside a TD a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td align="right">GBP 20.00</td>
 <td align="right">GBP 100.00</td>
 <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
```

I Guess thats what you are looking for as long as thee is ".00". If I were you, I would start using css even for this bit of code where you need to edit 3 places instead of one.

Comment: Just a note: This is not XHTML/HTML5 valid.