# TD element inner element height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have problem that I have element inside TD element and when I set element height to 100% it won't fill whole TD cell in height. Is it possible to fill whole whole TD height in inner element if its content has not same height?

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>
            1<br/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>
            2<br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
 width: 200px;
 position: relative; 
 }
 table tr td {
 background-color: blue;
 width: 47%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10px 1%;
 border: 1px solid #eee;
 }
 table tr td div {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 }
```

See following jsfiddle for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7esUV/

Comment: Tables are for tabulating data. Review your circumstance and determine whether a table is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with css, as the table cell height is based on it's contents. The div bases it's height on the height of it's parent, in this case the table cell. Thus, if there is only one line, that line's height is the hight of the table cell and thus of the div inside it.

Please see here why a div inside a table cell is a bad idea: [Is a DIV inside a TD a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea).

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's possible but your example doesn't work because you set `height:100%` to a div inside another element (the `td`) with an unspecified height

so just set an height to the td element or calculate the height of a cell via js and then apply that height to the div

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height of the tr and then the height of the element by pixels to match see my updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/peter/7esUV/3/

Comment: What if I cannot set TR height, then it is impossible to achieve without JavaScript?

Comment: See this updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/peter/7esUV/8/ you set the height by pixel for the div element then and not the TR

Answer (score 1):

If you can't set fixed height on `td` or `tr` (as you mentioned in your comment to one of the answers), I'm afraid the only way *is* Javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/xBjCE/

(I used jQuery in this example)