# Position Fixed not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here is my code which is working perfect in not IE browsers. The code is the part of the iframe which is loading in JQuery UI Dialogue.
Tested In IE 9.

```
<div style="height:400px;width:400px;overflow:auto">
<table>
<tr>
<td>content</td>

<td>

<div style="position:fixed;height:100px;">
Long Content.............
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This is my DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Do you need the <table> in there at all? Tables, and their content, are treated differently sometimes, and my guess is that 'diplay:fixed' isn't getting applied.

Comment: i don't like tables my self but there are more than 100 pages that are following same structure in my project.

Comment: You can't really complain about rendering inconsistencies when you have invalid HTML.

Comment: Did you make sure the DOCTYPE is on the first line of your HTML? IE doesn't recognize it if your DOCTYPE is preceded by anything, including an HTML comment.

Comment: @Sparky672 okay let change the question. How can i positioned fixed the content inside second TD ?

Answer (score 3):

It only works in non-IE browsers because they have better tolerance for bogus code.

Remove the extra `<td>` inside the `<td>`, and what in the world are you trying to achieve by putting a `position:fixed` inside a table cell? For the most part, `position:fixed` elements should be direct children of the `<body>` element...

Comment: extra <td> removed. Sir i am trying to achieve position fixed behavior on IE under this scenario. The problem is, i cant change the tables into DIV because there is lot of CODE.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nested `<td>` is valid, you should use another table to nest it.
And then [Is a DIV inside a TD a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea).
Don't know why you're using tables but this seems to be possible with divs.