# Is it valid to put h3 (or any heading) inside td tags?

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation, html-heading

The question is asked for TH tags, but I couldn't find one for TD tags.

Can I put headings inside `<td>` tags?

Comment: yes. See this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095803/what-elements-its-valid-to-place-inside-td-tag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`thead` is not `h3`, if you use `h3` inside `td` element, it is absolutely fine, but if you use `h3` as a direct child to `tr` is invalid.

Inorder to use `thead` you can use it like this

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>This is table head and not h3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td>Foot Cell</td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <h3>It's completely valid to put your h3 here</h3>
             Table cell
             <p>You can also use p tag here
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

But if you do it something like this, is invalid

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <h3>It's invalid</h3>
      <td>This is a cell</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

You can always check [here](http://validator.w3.org/) whether your markup is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks for this descriptive answer.

Answer (score 7):

No elements can appear inside a tag. Inside a [`td` *element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#edef-TD), i.e. between the `<td>` tag and the corresponding (possibly implicit) `</td>` tag, the content model is “flow content”. This effectively means anything that may appear inside the document body in general. So syntactically, `h3` is allowed.

The content model of `th` is the same as that of `td` in HTML4, but [in HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element), it is more limited and excludes heading elements, among other things.

The content model of the `tr` element (table row) allows only `th` and `td` children, so nothing else may appear *directly* inside it, only as wrapped in `th` or `td`.

These are the syntax rules and they do not imply that all content would be meaningful. In particular, a heading element inside `th` would be rather anomalous (what would it be a heading for? the `th` markup itself means a header cell), whereas in a `td` cell it could make perfect sense (e.g., in a table that compares two texts piecewise side by side).

Comment: Note for HTML5: the content model of `th` is different than the one of `td`. [`th`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) has: "Flow content […] with no […] heading content descendants".