# Firefox, IE9+ issue with div height 100% inside a td (working example on Chrome)

Tags: css, html, html-table

Take this: http://jsfiddle.net/zVscL/4/

```
.edit-me {
height:100%; /*does not behave the same as Chrome*/
width:10px;
border:1px solid blue;
background:red;
float:left;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Open the page on Chrome, then Firefox. The blue div does not inherit

Is there an explanation why this happens? Any fixes? Pure HTML/CSS solutions are preferable.

<del>I've been at this shit for hours trying to get CSS to behave and when I finally do FF does this. Eating up my development time.</del>

Comment: Similar issue discussed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea

Comment: Thanks, gotta let my boss know that divs in tds are a bad idea sometimes!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try setting the height of the `tr` and `td` to 100%:

```
tr, td { height: 100%; }
```

Generally speaking to get `height: 100%` to work correctly, all the heights of the element's parents must be set as well.

**EDIT:**

An alternative solution is to wrap the contents of the `td` with a container `div` and use absolute positioning to ensure the `.edit-me` div effectively has 100% height.

Here's what the HTML would look like:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="edit-me"></div>
                Foo
                <br/>
                Bar
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.edit-me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    width:10px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background:red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if you can do it with IE9+. I might unaccept the answer.

Comment: Sorry don't have easy access to IE9+ at the moment.  Feel free to unaccept if you'd like.  My only recommendation is try setting the height of the table and/or try setting the heights of the `td`, `tr`, `table` in pixels instead of percents.

Comment: No worries mate. Unfortunately my table has dynamic height so I can't use specific measurements.

Comment: Thanks for understand. =]  I think I have another idea that might work.  It involves a wrapper div and setting various things to `position: relative` and `position: absolute`.  I'll edit the answer above shortly.  Hopefully it'll work in IE.