# Python website - output items from a list

Tags: python, for-loop, web

I have a list which contains different information. I want to print them out so I did this:

```
<tr>
{% for item in aList %}
    <td class="dateIndex">
        <div>Date: {{item[0]}}</div>
        <div>Price: {{item[1]}}</div>
        <div>Status: {{item[2]}}</div>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

The problem is that all `items` go to a single line and the output looks like this:

```
Date: 1 200 available
Price:
Status:
```

When I'd like it to be:

```
Date: 1
Price: 200
Status: available
```

Any tips are appreciated.

**EDIT:**
aList contains items from a CSV file which looks like this
[image]

```
@app.route('/rent')
def rent():
    aList = readFile('static\\dates.csv')
    return render_template('rent.html', aList = aList)

def readFile(aFile):
    with open(aFile, 'r') as inFile: 
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        file = [row for row in reader]
    return file
```

Comment: What does `aList` contain?

Comment: Is your aList is a nested list ?

Comment: It's a CSV file, one line contains 3 items

Comment: So you are getting aLit somthing like this [[1, 200, 'available'],..] ?

Comment: Try using dot operator as i mentioned in answer below.

Comment: Sorry mate but it doesn't work

Comment: What browser are you using? See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 1):

```
def readFile(aFile):
    with open(aFile, 'r') as inFile: 
        reader = csv.reader(inFile)
        data = [row[0].split('\t') for row in reader]
    return data
```

First of all you should not use `file` as a variable name to hold your data as its a `built-in` type.

```
>>> file
<type 'file'>
>>>
>>> type(file)
<type 'type'>
```

Second it would be better if you would split it while reading your data from `csv` file instead of splitting it on template which looks ugly plus will break your template if you get some anonymous data.

```
<tr>
{% for item in aList %}
    <td class="dateIndex">
        <div>Date: {{item.0}}</div>
        <div>Price: {{item.1}}</div>
        <div>Status: {{item.2}}</div>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

You should use `dot` opertator to point the index at template level.

Comment: Can you add in your question what you are getting in aList exactly ? and how your sending it to your template?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by what I get in aList. As for seding I just added it.

Comment: Can you also include the implimentation of readFile('static\\dates.csv') in your question.

Comment: I tried this on django, and it is working fine as you expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues here.

First, you will probably need to create a tr for every result

```
{% for item in aList %}
<tr>
    <td class="dateIndex">
        <div>Date: {{item.0}}</div>
        <div>Price: {{item.1}}</div>
        <div>Status: {{item.2}}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Second, you are probably experiencing some browser issue with divs appearing in td's.

At the very least, you should ensure you divs are displaying as block level elements and not inline....

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution finally.

it kept the item as a list `['1\t200\tavailable']`
so splitting everything in between \t with `.split()` worked perfectly

```
<div>Date: {{item[0].split('\t')[0]}}</div>
<div>Price: {{item[0].split('\t')[1]}}</div>
<div>Status: {{item[0].split('\t')[2]}}</div>
```

Comment: I asked you above whether you are getting comma seperated list but it seems you were getting space tab between vales.