# Can we put any tag inside tbody of table element in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I have a very peculiar use case which requires me to use two ng-repeats. 
One array is of dates and another contains some date in form of associated array with argument as those dates.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <!-- <tr ng-repeat="datum in data[date]"> -->
    <td> {{date}} </td>
    <td> {{datum.carName}} {{datum.regNumber}}</td>
    <td> {{datum.driverName}} </td>
    <td> {{datum.startTime}} </td>
    <td> {{datum.endTime}} </td>
    <td> {{datum.trip.sourceName}}</td>
    <td> {{datum.trip.destinationName}} </td>
    <!-- </tr> -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now HTML doesn't allow me to use any another tags inside `tbody` apart from `tr` and `td`. Also I know that we cannot have two ng-repeats inside a tag so what could be the workaround for this ?  Can I insert any other tag ?

Comment: You cannot insert other tags directly under `tbody`.

Comment: Then is there a way to solve this issue @MaihanNijat

Comment: This sounds like you should merge the contents of `data` and `dates` before sticking it in your template view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't put just any element you want (like a `<div>`, for example) inside `<tbody>`. What you *can* do is repeat `<tbody>` and then repeat `<tr>` within each `<tbody>`

```
<tbody  ng-repeat="date in dates">    
    <tr ng-repeat="datum in data[date]">
```

There are no limits on having more than one `<tbody>`

Comment: I don't think you can have multiple tbody within a table. I just tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: You can have as many `tbody` elements are you like. A table consists of 0-1 thead, 0-1 tfoot and 1 or more tbody.

Comment: @SarasArya if it's not working it's because something else is wrong

Comment: Yes I just harcoded with two tbody's and it works. But when I apply the above solution the table vanishes

Comment: I only copied what you had for scope arrays... check your scope

Comment: Yes.. It works Thank you. So the issue was, my second array had no data. That is why the table was blank.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-if="0" ng-repeat-start="date in dates"></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="datum in data[date]">
            <td> {{date}} </td>
            <td> {{datum.carName}} {{datum.regNumber}}</td>
            <td> {{datum.driverName}} </td>
            <td> {{datum.startTime}} </td>
            <td> {{datum.endTime}} </td>
            <td> {{datum.trip.sourceName}}</td>
            <td> {{datum.trip.destinationName}} </td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-if="0" ng-repeat-end></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This uses a combination of `ng-if` and `ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end`. Here `ng-if="0"` ensures that the element won't be rendered.

Answer (score -3):

You can always other tags inside the td.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <div>here</div>
      <p>there</p>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: No, you cannot. That is invalid HTML and error recovery in browsers generally gives undesirable results.

Comment: @Quentin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea

Comment: That question is asking about elements inside a `td` not a `tr`.

Comment: You answered with correct text...but code example is wrong