# Hover-over div inside of a table

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to create a hover-over div that appears when a user hovers over images inside a td. This would look similar to when you hover over an image that has a title attribute:

[image]

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea) question, a div inside a table is valid HTML but I would need to set the internal div to `position: absolute;` and the containing td `position: relative;` and according to one of the answers in the thread this could cause problems:

> If you want to use `position: absolute;` on the div with position:
>   relative; on the td you will run into issues. FF, safari, and chrome
>   (mac, not PC though) will not position the div relative to the td
>   (like you would expect)

So how could I show a div that appears when hovering over the images contained in the td?

Comment: Hey I found this one about positioning div inside td http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<td alt='hover text' title='hover text'>
```

alt and title work with different browsers, and this won't work on most mobile browsers.

Comment: I'm looking to create my own div and not use the title or alt attributes.

Answer (score -1):

Add a div with `position:relative` to the `td` (wrapped around the td content) and then you can add your absolutely positioned div inside the relative one.

Or, if you only need a title-like tooltip, use the `title` attribute on your `td`

Comment: Not sure why this was marked down...?  It's actually a viable way of achieving what OP requires... You cannot position a table cell,so a nested div is required.