# How to approach this HTML table design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I've created a mockup of design in Photoshop and now I want to make a 'working' mockup version using HTML and CSS. I'm looking for advice on the best way to approach this.

The image mockup is below (ignore the green arrows on the right of the table);

[image: Mockup Table]

The design itself is basically a table with a fixed left-hand column and scrollable center content.

I've tried to replicate a *basic* version of this using data tables and bootstrap, [see link here](https://codepen.io/qubjohnny/pen/bGdbOvZ) and a working snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "300px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   true,
        sorting: false
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Bootstrap jquery dataTable fixed columns</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap4.min.css'>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="container" style="width:80%">
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Room</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Room Name</td>
        <td>12am</td>
        <td>1am</td>
        <td>2am</td>
        <td>3am</td>
        <td>4am</td>
        <td>5am</td>
        <td>6am</td>
        <td>7am</td>
        <td>8am</td>
        <td>9am</td>
        <td>10am</td>
        <td>11am</td>
        <td>12pm</td>
        <td>1pm</td>
        <td>2pm</td>
        <td>3pm</td>
        <td>4pm</td>
        <td>5pm</td>
        <td>6pm</td>
        <td>7pm</td>
        <td>8pm</td>
        <td>9pm</td>
        <td>10pm</td>
        <td>11pm</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.3.0/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I was hoping I could recreate this design using `<div>`s within the table cells, and style them using CSS. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea) already but it's quite old and I'm wondering if things have moved on since that answers?

- Would this be valid HTML?
- Can anyone see any issues or a better way of creating this in HTML / CSS?

Note I will be using Bootstrap, HTML, and CSS. Not necessarily DataTables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312236/how-do-i-create-an-html-table-with-a-fixed-frozen-left-column-and-a-scrollable-b

Comment: It looks like a resource-based scheduling calendar, to me. Have you considered using something ready-made? e.g. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-standard-view-demo . See https://fullcalendar.io/ for more details. (There are other similar libraries available, I just happen to think that one is quite good).