# Why can't a div be used inside a table?

Tags: html, reactjs, semantic-markup

i'm working with some CRUDS using React, but when I added divs to help organize the buttons, this error or warning appears:
VM72 react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): `<input>` cannot appear as a child of `<table>`.
This is my code

```
 <tbody>
          {recolectores.map((reco) => (
            <tr key={reco.id}>
              <td>{reco.id}</td>
              <td>{reco.primer_nombre + " " + reco.primer_apellido}</td>
              <td>{reco.direccion}</td>
              <td>{reco.correo}</td>
              <td>
                <React.Fragment>
                  <div className="flex flex-wrap  space-x-1">
                    {reco?.rutas?.map((ruta) => (
                      <div className="badge  badge-md " key={ruta?.id}>
                        {ruta?.nombre}
                      </div>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              </td>
```

As it is, I've heard about react fragments, but the problem remains
Someone knows how to get this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a DIV inside a TD a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Check the permitted parent of [DIV](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) element, [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#flow_content)

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that the problematic node is not a div, it's an input.  Any chance you've got an `<input>` nested directly underneath a `<table>` element somewhere in your code not shown above? That won't work; table has a strict content model.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right. The problem was caused cause i rendered a modal inside the table accidentally.It works now!